# Geth --RPC taking a long time

Tags: go-ethereum

The synchronization that has been working for about 12 hours has slowed from 2048 16ms to 2048 2~3 mins.  It has been telling me that my clock is off my seconds but I re-synced the clock just now. Any idea what caused the sudden jump in time for block sync?

Comment: this is not a question.

Comment: @Ellie I thought the question was clear enough.  My bad.  I added it.

Comment: Network latency in your part of the world during different times of the day? Perhaps your peers have either gone offline, or are similarly affected by latency in their part of the world?

Comment: On this site, it is recommended to put the question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Not Clear enough. The first blocks of the blockchain are almost empty (in transactions), the recent blocks are way difficult to check. On my mac mini, the first 2048 blocks need 2s but the most recent > 1min.

There are two factors: the checks and the network. In your case, i suppose that is computation time.